# boot to windows from aptio BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu, but it has overridden my windows boot option, so now it boots to grub. (I can still select windows from there). I want my computer to boot to windows as I only incidentally use ubuntu, and will then boot that from the last page in the bios where I can boot to a certain os once without changing the boot order. I have looked at the 'add boot option...', but I don't know how I should add windows to it. Anyone have an idea? I might upload some pictures when I get home to show what my boot system looks like currently.

Comment: Did you even install Windows or Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: Windows: yes. Ubuntu: I am not sure but I think so. How can I find that? Shall I look for something in the grub settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of a file called `bkpbootx64.efi` suggests that you've run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and told it to back up your boot loaders and replace the originals with copies of GRUB. (To be sure, the option to do this isn't really labeled as such.) This is unnecessary 90% or more of the time and complicates matters. Thus, you might want to re-run Boot Repair, enter the Advanced options page, and select the option to restore backups. This will return your boot loaders to a more standard configuration. OTOH, if you've got one of the ~10% of computers with badly broken EFIs that need this ugly hack, making this change may make it impossible to boot to Linux. This change will also not set Windows to boot by default (unless you've got one of those broken EFIs, in which case you then won't be able to boot Linux at all).

To set Windows as the default boot option, you can use `efibootmgr` in Linux or `bcdedit` in Windows, as in:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

Scan the `Boot####` entries for the one that boots `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` and another that boots Linux (probably `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` or `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` in your case). Note the numbers and use them; for instance, if Windows is `Boot0003` and Ubuntu is `Boot0002`:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0002
```

This sets Windows to boot first and Linux to boot second. (Note, however, that if your Windows boot loader has been backed up to another name, `bootmgfw.efi` will be another copy of GRUB, and you'll need to search instead for `bkpbootmgfw.efi` or some other file. It might not even be present; I don't recall offhand if Boot Repair creates EFI entries for the real Windows boot loader.)

The Windows `bcdedit` command is simpler. You'd use it from an *Administrator* Command Prompt window:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

In either case, when you reboot you should boot straight into Windows. To boot to Linux, you'll need to use the firmware's built-in boot manager.

Alternatively, you can adjust GRUB so that Windows boots by default. There's a tool called [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) that's supposed to make this relatively easy, but I've never used it, so I can't provide much guidance.

Yet another option is to install a third-party boot manager, such as my [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) In the case of rEFInd, you can set the default OS on the `default_selection` line in `refind.conf`. Set the timeout to a low value and the computer will boot Windows with but a brief delay.

Comment: Hi, this looks interesting. I just entered `bcdedit` only to see my default configuration, and the identifier `{bootmgr}` already has the path `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`, so I am not sure wether it would help. There is only one other option called `{current}`, which has path `\WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi`. I will boot into ubuntu now to see what `efibootmgr -v` gives me.

Comment: So I reverted the backup, and then set the right boot order, so efi should boot first to `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`, but this sends me straight to grub. The boot repair utility generated a lot of output and gave me the [dump url](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7097012/). I just want to boot my computer only to windows (using the best way as bkpbootx64.efi doesn't sound efficient), and have the grub in my efi bootlist (so I can press escape and select ubuntu/grub to be able to chose from all of my linux distro's).

Comment: So what I think is that `bootmgfw.efi` is overwritten to boot to grub, correct?

Comment: And what you say in [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html) document, when booting to `bootmgfw.efi` it indeed shows some text, too fast to read and then boots into grub. (if I select the normal ubuntu option, it doesn't do that).

Comment: Commentoverflow. It seemed to be booting `bkpbootmgw.efi` just fine, so I backed up `bootmgfw.efi` and renamed the bkp file so it is called `bootmgfw.efi` (cleaning up boot-repairs stuff). When I started, windows directly came with an error `0x00225`, and I remember that from some time ago. Rebooting fixes it, but in the past this error came up multiple times. It is just a pity that windows can't regenerate it's efi file, so I can then just change the boot order and everything will work fine. Trying your bcdedit tip, it might regenerate (I think).

Comment: Windows hasn't crashed after 4 times of rebooting. Other strange things happen though. I have ubuntu twice in my efi boot list, so I changed that. As grub was a mess, I also ran `update-grub`. After rebooting, I still have two ubuntu options, and my grub is still a mess. When running `efibootmgr` it shows me two ubuntu options. There is really something strange going on. I hope you can also help me out on this one.

Comment: I'm not a fan of GRUB. It's overly complex and difficult to configure. I can't really offer any suggestions on fixing its "mess," particularly not without details of how it's messy. Personally, I'd remove GRUB and install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in its place -- but as I maintain rEFInd, I'm biased. As to the boot options in NVRAM, they may be multiplying because of a known bug in shim (`shimx64.efi`), which is required for Secure Boot booting of Linux. Disabling Secure Boot and booting straight to `grubx64.efi` (or `refind_x64.efi`) may stop them from multiplying.

Comment: Still, thank you for your answer. The ubuntu boot option indeed points to shimx64.efi, so that might be the reason. I will fix grub sometime, but I don't want to put more time in it, as I hardly ever use ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If Windows was installed in UEFI mode, its bootloader will be found at:

```
\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Give this path to "Add boot option"; it'll become accessible if you press Esc at the Asus logo.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but This did not work. I however opened the grub boot entry, and found that the path was \EFI\Boot\bkpbootx64.efi. This works.