# What is the difference between Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi and Windows UEFI bkpbootx64.efi?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub2

My computer screen while starting computer

[image]

Also help me by explaining why windows UEFI loader was first taking me to windows but now is redirecting back to this window.

Comment: The title and body of this question are entirely different. Could you edit this question or split it up into two questions?

Comment: @TheKB we cant make so long question here,I wont mind if you answer the first question itself,And sorry because I  am new here.

Comment: bkpbootx64.efi is not a standard windows boot file. Have you modified your computer in any way?

Comment: I have installed ubuntu alongside windows and run a grub2 boot-repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bkpbootx64.efi is a backup regularly created by Boot-Repair. With Windows the bootx64.efi is just really a copy of Windows bootmgfw.efi. And bootx64.efi is a fallback or hard drive boot entry in UEFI.

But Boot-Repair with its 'Use the standard EFI file` in advanced options creates the bkpbootx64.efi and makes bootx64.efi a copy of shimx64.efi so fallback or hard drive boot entry in UEFI really boots grub not Windows.

About the only way to tell which is which is by checking file size or what actually boots. If Boot-Repair created 25_custom for all the HP entries you probably can delete most or all of them.

Edit 25_custom entries created by Boot-Repair:

```
sudo cp -a /etc/grub.d/25_custom /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom
```

turn off execute bit or it will run backup also

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/25_custom
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

`bootmgfw.efi` - This is the windows UEFI boot manager. [Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336950.aspx)

`bkpbootx64.efi` - This is a back-up done by Boot Repair when it replaces other boot loaders with GRUB. [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/727065/boot-to-windows-from-aptio-bios)